# Check on capital OR lowercase value - Google script

Tags: google-sheets

I want to check if columns A B and C are filled with 'Yes' or 'yes' if so a action will follow.

I have this piece of code, and this is working for capitalized 'Yes'

```
if([1,2,3].indexOf(e.range.getColumn()) > -1) {
    if (Col1 == "Yes" && Col2 == "Yes" && Col3 == "Yes") {Some action here}
```

But when I add `||` (OR) to it, the code fails.

```
if([1,2,3].indexOf(e.range.getColumn()) > -1) {
    if ((Col1 == "Yes"||"yes") && (Col2 == "Yes"||"yes")  && (Col3 == "Yes"||"yes") ) {Some action here}
```

Hoping for some help here ;)

Comment: Have you tried `if ((Col1 == "Yes" || Col1 == "yes") && ....` or `if ((Col1.toLowerCase() == "yes") && ...`

Comment: if ((Col1 == "Yes" || Col1 == "yes") && ....  seems to work. The .toLowerCase()  solution not.

Comment: OK. Have converted my comment into a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement the current approach may be cumbersome. A conditional count (case insensitive) of the three columns looking for "Yes" and then further action conditional on the result being `3` might be a little simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your OR statement is not right - you need to specify the variable that you are checking again. For instance:

```
if([1,2,3].indexOf(e.range.getColumn()) > -1) {
    if ((Col1 == "Yes" || Col1 == "yes") && (Col2 == "Yes" || Col2 == "yes")  && (Col3 == "Yes" || Col3 == "yes") ) {Some action here}
```